# Delete rows in my db with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what my DB looks like:

[image]

I am trying to delete all the records from both these tables where `ID = 8`.
This is what I've tried:

```
DELETE from users1,pontaj WHERE users1.id, pontaj.id  IN(8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had defined `potaj` table with `pontaj.id` as

```
CREATE TABLE pontaj (
  id int, foreign key(id) references users1(id)
         on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

then just executing

```
DELETE from users1 WHERE users1.id IN(8)
```

would have deleted records from both parent and child tables.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but If I run this as a SQL command, I get an error. Should I delete pontaj table, then run the query ?

Comment: @ExtremeSwat: No. If `users1.id` has an `index` defined on it, this solution should work. Otherwise define a `key(id)` in `users1` tables. But your images map shows that the referred field is a `primary key` and hence it should have worked without any issue.

Comment: No effect whatsoever over the other 2 tables.The command just deletes the id from the 1'st table hmm...

Comment: @ExtremeSwat: Perhaps the child fields are defined with `on delete set null`.

Comment: @ExtremeSwat: Run `show create table pontaj;` and `show create table salariu;` and see how the child columns are defined as.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AU... ) 
Can't get the whole thing, the table where I get the info is not resizable, anyways thanks for the tip I'll use it in future. ( I have used 3 diffrent queries and fixed up my stuff)

Comment: Thats OK. You however got a solution.

Comment: Yup, anyways I'm doing this for a college project, and it's the 1'st time I use mySQL with VB.NET